# Can a moderator suppress notifications being sent to "followers" when an edit is made?

Tags: support, notifications, follow-post

I spotted an error in an answer, which happened to have been written by a moderator. I wrote a comment notifying them of this and "followed" the answer to get a notification when the answer was updated, intending to upvote later once corrected.

However, despite the answer later being updated (and my comment deleted), I received no notification.

Is it possible that the moderator suppressed notifications being sent when they edited their own answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Trivial" edits, those that are under 6 characters (2 if it's code), don't notify the OP when done by another user. Similarly, followers don't get notifications for others' trivial edits either, I'm pretty sure. And you're never notified that your comments are deleted.

Diamond moderators don't have any obvious "suppress notifications" functionality, at least not that I know of as a diamond moderator. If it wasn't a trivial edit, I would check the post's timeline to see if anything happened (post deletion/undeletion?).

I feel pretty confident that the moderator wasn't trying to prevent you from seeing the notification. There's just no reason for that.